# Is there duty free in San Diego airport?

Tags: duty-free, san-diego

I'll be flying international from San Diego soon and need to buy a couple things that duty free is best for. Yet looking at the SAN website, I can only see one typical duty free shop, which is only open 3 days a week, 2 hour each day.

If anyone flew recently from SAN, can you confirm the situation?

Note: the question is about December 2021.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I flew a couple of days ago and can confirm first hand that the SAN website is *generally* correct.  There really is only one duty free shop (in the typical sense), called Sky Free Shop, in terminal 2.  And it normally is open as stated on SAN website: Mon, Fri, Sunday 10:30 am-12:30 pm, closed all other times.

I say *generally*, because sometimes they may be randomly open at other times, or, as it happened in my case, half of the shop was open on Wednesday afternoon, around 4 pm.  There was a single employee in the store. I asked him about the opening hours - to which he replied that they'd normally be closed, but he decided to open for a few hours to make extra sales in pre-christmas season.

As I said, only half the shop was open, selling a lot of perfumes and cosmetics and a very limited selection of alcohol and cigarettes. There was nothing else, not even chocolates, available.  So, don't rely on it being there and open.